# How to change Representation of Many to Many related object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want the complete related model on GET and use the id's on CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE.
I try to use to_representation.
So i want to create an array of dicts called users which should show the complete users.

But i get the error "unhashable type: 'ReturnDict'" when i add the dict in the object, it works fine if i would do it for a single user by writing to the array directly.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #users = UserSerializer(many=True)
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'street', 'city', 'postal_code', 'state', 'company_form', 'users', 'created_at', 'updated_at']        

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(CompanySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['company_form'] = CompanyFormSerializer(instance.company_form).data
        representation['users'] = []
        for entry in instance.users.all():
            user = {UserSerializer(entry).data}
            representation['users'].extend(user)
        return representation
```

Comment: Why did you comment out `users = UserSerializer(many=True)`?

Comment: Furthermore that is completely logic: you should not use `user = {...}`, but just `user = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do this manually, you can add serializers to your serializer, like:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    company_form = CompanyFormSerializer()
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'street', 'city', 'postal_code', 'state', 'company_form', 'users', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

For more information, see the [*Dealing with nested objects* section of the *Django REST Framework documentation*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).

Your `to_representation` model was wrong on two parts:

1. you wrapped the result of the `.data` in a set, but as you found out, a dictionary can not be placed in a dictionary, since a set is mutable; and
2. you should use `.append(..)` instead of `.extend(..)` here.

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(CompanySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    representation['company_form'] = CompanyFormSerializer(instance.company_form).data
    representation['users'] = []
    for entry in instance.users.all():
        user = UserSerializer(entry).data
        representation['users'].append(user)
    return representation
```

But that being said, it is in my opinion, bad software design to aim to do this yourself. Django has a lot of tooling to handle relationships properly through URIs, etc.

Comment: As stated, I want the complete related model on GET and use the id's on CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE. With this i cannot do this

Comment: @NicoBleiler: you can, it is only a matter of configuering it properly. You will here obtain the serialized data of related users. In fact, by overriding `to_representation`, you actually make it worse since now the two functions are no longer each other's inverse.

Comment: Thanks man, now it is working, will accept it in 4 minutes when SO allows me to do so, i am quite new to both python and django.